# How to fetch mysql value and put it into a music playlist in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch my mysql value into a jq music plyalist , my playlist requires as below

```
var myPlaylist = [

    {
        mp3:'demo/mix/1.mp3',
        oga:'mix/1.ogg',
        title:'masum',
        artist:'masum',
        rating:4,
        buy:'#',
        price:'0.99',
        duration:'0:30',

    },
    {
        mp3:'demo/mix/2.mp3',
        oga:'mix/2.ogg',
        title:'funny',
        artist:'ribon',
        rating:4,
        buy:'#',
        price:'0.99',
        duration:'0:30',

    }
];
```

How can i put my mysql value in the playlist in php ?
my mysql database is as like as below:

song_id song_title  song_type   song_name   user_id

Comment: ajax, then just insert them in PHP

Answer (score 0):

We cant do the whole code for you, but here is a general example of how to do it:

In your, lets say, index.php file:

```
var myPlaylist = [
<?php
    mysql_connect( //your connect infor );
    $res = mysql_query( // your query );
    for( $i=0; $r = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ); $i++ ){
        echo "
            {
                mp3:'" . $r['filename'] . "',
                oga:'" . $r['ogg_filename'] . "',
                title:'" . $r['title'] . "',
                artist:'" . $r['artist'] . "',
                rating:4,
                buy:'#',
                price:'0.99',
                duration:'0:30',

            },            
        ";
    }
?>
]
```

And so on. A good place for you to start might be at the W3Schools tutorial on Php and MySQL:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: Dear I know how to fetch mysql vale in php , whatever thank you for your reply,but main prb is "," I need "," after each myPlaylist "}" if user song is multiple and I need no "," if your song is one. I can not do it.

Comment: So all you need is to remove the tailing "," from the last element in the list?

Comment: Yes, if fetch function got only one song then loop will be execute 1 times then I dont need "," after myplaylist parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert a php array (assuming your results are like this, from your db query) into a javascript object, then echo out the resulting string into your script tags after your javascript variable declaration.

json_encode() automatically wraps your results in square brackets and curly brackets appropriately

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$result = array(
    array(
        "mp3" => 'demo/mix/1.mp3',
        "oga" => 'mix/1.ogg',
        "title" => "masum",
        "artist" => "masum",
        "rating" => 4,
        "buy" => '#',
        "price" => "0.99",
        "duration" => "0:30"
    ),
    array (
        "mp3" => 'demo/mix/2.mp3',
        "oga" => 'mix/2.ogg',
        "title" => "masum",
        "artist" => "masum",
        "rating" => 5,
        "buy" => '#',
        "price" => "1.99",
        "duration" => "0:45"
    )
);

$js = json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); //don't escape forward slashes

?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo "var playlist= " . $js . ";\n"; ?>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This returns:

```
var playlist= [{
    "mp3":"demo\/mix\/1.mp3",
    "oga":"mix\/1.ogg",
    "title":"masum",
    "artist":"masum",
    "rating":4,
    "buy":"#",
    "price":"0.99",
    "duration":"0:30"
},
{
    "mp3":"demo\/mix\/2.mp3",
    "oga":"mix\/2.ogg",
    "title":"masum",
    "artist":"masum",
    "rating":5,
    "buy":"#",
    "price":"1.99",
    "duration":"0:45"
}];
```

Comment: thank you but I did it another way.I have tried your code but it did not work.